# Find if a set of points can form a regular polygon or not?

Tags: java, android, math

Is there any way to find out if a given set points can form a regular polygon?I,e suppose i have 6 points i want to find out if these points can form a regular hexagon

Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: The properties of a regular polygon are well known: equal distances from one point to its neighbours, and equal angles of a certain size. Go ahead and start coding.

Comment: Do you have 2 points named p1? this makes 7 points... Anyway a regular poligon is inscribed into a circumference. Once You know the number of points and their coordinates, you can establish if they are all at the same distance from the center and if they are located at the proper angles (360 / numPoints)

Comment: No i don't have 2 points,actually i have n points and i have to find out the points which form a regular hexagon from these points

Comment: How will i find the center of that circle?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Find the center:

   Sum up all x coordinates and all y coordinates and devide both of the sums by the number of points to get the coordinates of the center point (we'll call this point *C*).
2. Check, if all of the points have the same distance to *C*. If not, it's not regular and you are done. Allow small differences, since floating point values have limited precission.
3. Calculate the angles of all points in a polar coordinate system centered at *C*. For point p you can use `Math.atan2(P.y-C.y, P.x-C.x)` to get the angle. The polygon is regular if and only if all angles are different and all differences between those angles are multiples of `(Math.PI*2) / (number of points)`.(I'll call this value `d`). Of course you won't get exact values.

   **Note:** You can check this by checking that a) all differences of one angle to all other angles are multiples of `d` and b) for each of the intervals `[-pi, -pi+d), [-pi+d, -pi+2*d), [-pi+2*d, -pi+3*d), ..., [pi-d, pi]` there is exactly one angle that's in that interval. However, since you'll want to allow small errors in the calculation you'll need find the smallest angle and move all intervals so that this angle lies in the middle of the first interval (You definetly don't want the angles to be at the interval borders).

This way you'll get the result in asymptotically optimal time, i.e. `O(n)` where n is the number of points.